# foreign and special characters not displaying

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have an e-commerce website which is in polish and the product categories are stored in the database (in polish)

For some reason the special foreign characters are not displaying but only in certain parts of the website.

characters like ł, ą, ó and many more.

the thing is they display perfectly in the main body of the category page but they are also displayed down the left hand side of the page as an alternative navigation and it is this left side nav which they are not displaying correctly...they are showing up as ? or �

I have checked the table in the database and it is stored as utf8_general_ci

I have checked the "left-nav.php" file which is included in the page and it is encoded in UTF8.

I even checked the category page file even though it displays the characters correctly in the main body, and it is also saved in UTF8.

I have this line of code in my site header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I use HeidiSQL to manage my database and they are stored correctly in the database

am I missing something? and what can I do to fix this?

Why would special characters like these display correctly in some places but not others?

Here is the code for the top category in the left navigation

```
<?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM RAE_categories_pl WHERE categoryID = '".$category."'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);?>
    <div class="liSelect"><img src="images/arrowdown_off.gif" style="padding:0px; margin:0px -10px 0 0;float:right;"><a class="select" href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/products/<?php echo $result['categoryID'];?>"><?php echo $result['categoryName'];?></a></div>
    <?php
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT RAE_sub_categories_pl.categoryName AS subCatName, RAE_sub_categories_pl.categoryID AS subCatID FROM RAE_sub_categories_pl INNER JOIN RAE_products_pl ON RAE_products_pl.subCategory = RAE_sub_categories_pl.categoryID AND RAE_products_pl.active = 1 WHERE RAE_sub_categories_pl.parentCatID = '$category' GROUP BY RAE_sub_categories_pl.categoryID");
    while ($result2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
    {?>
        <div class="liul">
                <div class="ulli">
                    <a href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/equipment/" . $category . "/" . $result2['subCatID'];?>"><?php echo $result2['subCatName']?></a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` at the top of the script

Comment: It's impossible to say, why the characters broke, until you show us php code, responsible for database interaction

Comment: OK i ammended my question

Comment: @Kevlar Check the code, where you are connecting to MySQL and make sure, that you call `$con->set_charset("utf8")` after you connect.

Comment: @user4035 thankyou that has indeed fixed my problem :) accepted your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure, that you are using `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` after connecting to MySQL in php scripts, generating bad characters:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pw", "db");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Failed to connect to mySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_errno());
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Comment: thanks This has help me :) I just added "$con->set_charset("utf8");" below my connection code and it fixed it :) thanks again

Comment: saved my day ;] also everybody who is facing this issue should consider adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` in the .php file where special characters are shown together with that mysqli function show in the answer above!

Answer (score 0):

For foreign language support make Collation of the database table's corresponding field to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: add this in head section. <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

Comment: plz check once the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077085/saving-malayalam-text-to-database

Answer (score 0):

Try to set column collation to: `utf8_polish_ci`

example:

> some_field VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci',

Answer (score 0):

those who are using mysql can add this line to their connect section to fix special character display issue

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

for mysqli users it would be

```
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");
```